# TouchableOpacity border radius breaks background color on Android - React Native

Tags: ios, css, react-native

I have a button that's styled as a TouchableOpacity.

On iOS this button has a white background and round corners, but in Android the background color doesn't get applied when there's a border-radius, it does when I take it out. border-radius also doesn't appear to have any effect regardless of whether there's a background color or not in Android.

I know I can use some conditional based on the platform, but I'd like to know if it's possible to have the same between the two platforms with the same code.

```js
export const SomeButton = styled.TouchableOpacity`
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 4
  background: white;
`
```

Comment: AFAIK it is `borderRadius`, without the "-" and camelCased

Comment: It's because I'm using styled-components. It does the same using regular objects and borderRadius

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. I had to roll back the react-native to 0.60.5